# How do I select all vertices in edit mode?

Tags: vertices

What's the tool I need to use to select all vertices? I'm making a horn, and need to select all vertices in the Bezier curves to then put a cylinder around them.

Answer (score 3):

press <kbd>A</kbd> twice

---

If you want a simple horn shape you can use the Data>Geometry>Bevel slider in the Properties of the BezierCurve to give you curve depth. Be sure to set the Shape>Fill to Full, increase the Geometry>Bevel above 0 to give it depth, and increase the Geometry>Resolution to make it more rounded:

[image]
You can then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale the diameter at the vertices.

You could even use a non circular <s>Mesh</s> *BezierCurve* as Bevel Object, and twist the vertices with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to get a cartoony twisted horn look.

Comment: Can use `<kbd>A</kbd>` for keyboard key markup.  Hit the edit button on any q / a to see markup used.

Comment: Thank you @batFINGER, btw, why doesn't the @ work here?

Comment: Yes, the tooltip below the comment says it should work. Or does it work but just doesn't show up as link?

Comment: It notifies the user in their inbox.  Too lazy to find,  there's docs on it somewhere in tour. Basic rule of thumb,  If `@b<tab>` doesn't autocomplete (to `@batFINGER`) then it's not required, just las I don't need @FelixBode in this because it is a comment on your answer.

Comment: Can I add that A is a toggle. If you have any elements selected on first press it will select none, then all, then none. etc.  If nothing is selected on first press it will select all, **then none**, then all etc. (in latter case hitting twice will go back to selecting none)